# Difference between abstract method of abstract class and abstract method of interface in java

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

In Java is there any major difference between abstract method of abstract class and abstract method of interface except their access privilege? Please enlighten me. I am using Java7.

Comment: Yes. But you need to tell us which version of Java you're interested in.

Comment: I don't think interfaces have `abstract` methods per say, but simple have a contractual requirement which implementations must meet.  All  methods declared by a interface must be public.  You can't have a abstract method, without the class been abstract

Comment: @MadProgrammer From [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se6/html/interfaces.html#9.4): "Every method declaration in the body of an interface is implicitly `abstract`"

Comment: @Andreas Yeah, I kind of had in my head that they didn't term it that way, but, hay, what do I know :P

Comment: I am using java7. I just wanted to know that is there any difference between the abstract method of Abstract class and the abstract method of interface except their access specifier.

Comment: You may need to narrow down your question for us.  I can think of one major difference, and that has to do with the possibility that a class can implement two interfaces, where both interfaces declare the same method signature or a method signature that is almost the same but different enough to cause conflicts; but maybe that can happen if a class extends an abstract class and implements an interface that declares a similar method.  I'd have to look it up to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Technically No difference between the methods or it's signature - between `abstract` class and `interface`. But the usage of the methods make the difference.

```
public class Son extends AbstractChild , Father{//Cannot do as multiple inheritance not supported

}

public class Son extends AbstractChild implements Naughtiness, Cuteness{//Allowed}
```

As per JLS, the interface's methods are `public` and `abstract` and as you mentioned the access modifier for interface is defaulted to `public`.

However with Java 8, the interface is the game changer. Interface will have the same power of an abstract classes where you can have the default implementation of the method.

For more info, refer - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html

Answer (score 0):

On the one hand you have some technical differences:

- Interface methods are implicitely `public abstract`
- Interfaces can use `extends` multiple times
- Abstract class can contain some implemented functionalities (Interfaces can have it only in JDK 8+)

In practice developers use them to implement little bit different functionalities:

- Abstract classes are used mostly on top of inheritance trees ( assume classes Animal, Cat extends Animal, Dog extends Animal). Animal may have some functionalities which are common for all animals ( for example getName())
- Interfaces just mark behavior. (Annoyable interface, Mosquito implements Annoyable, Telemarketer implements Annoyable). Telemarketer and Mosquito both have method `annoy()`.

Answer (score 0):

An abstract method does not contain a default implementation and relies on an implementation class.  The abstract method ends in a ;  and does not use the { } because the method can not contain an implementation. Its subclass must provide implementation.  An abstract class can have abstract and non-abstract methods.  the purpose of the abstract class is to hide the internal detail and show only the implementation to the user.